# Responsive portfolio gallery is not working on Android and iMac

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, responsive

I just designed this website  http://irenovate.in/snapdeal.html and its portfolio gallery is working on computer led, systems and laptop, but **not in Android mobile and iMac**. Anybody can help me please that why it's happening?

Comment: What is it doing wrong in android and imac?

Answer (score 0):

Checked your site. Whenever you site browsed on mobile means on lower resolution then it loads the image from this path `img/works/S-2@2x.jpg` which does not exists on your server either change that path to `img/works/S-2.jpg` or create a lower resolution image of  `img/works/S-2@2x.jpg`

```
<div class="item"><a href="img/works/S-2.jpg" title="SNAPDEAL PROJECT" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="img/works/S-2@2x.jpg"><img src="img/works/S-2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="img"></a></div>
```